# RecyclerView not populating from Room DB ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, android-room, viewmodel

I'm trying to show data from db to RecyclerView from ViewModel, but unable to see the list on home screen. I'm new to MVVM model.

I've implemented POJO class for product and implemented Room DB using that class. Also recyclerview has been implemented using ViewModel class.

With this I'm unable to populate data from db, but the database is updating with new entries.

Following is my code snippets, kindly let me know if you need anything else to debug.

HomeActivity

```
public static List<ProductModel> productModels = null;
public static RoomDBMaster dbMaster = null;
private static Button btnScan = null;
private static RecyclerView recyclerView;
private static ProductListAdapter adapter;

public static ProductViewModel productViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    initUI();

    btnScan.setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(HomeActivity.this, QRScannerActivity.class)));
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initUI();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    initUI();
}

private void initUI() {

    btnScan = findViewById(R.id.btn_scan_qr);

    if (dbMaster == null) {
        dbMaster = RoomDBMaster.getDatabase(getApplicationContext());
    }

    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_product_list);
    final ProductListAdapter adapter = new ProductListAdapter(new ProductListAdapter.ProductDiff());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    try {
        productViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ProductViewModel.class);
        productViewModel.getAllProducts().observe(this, products -> {
            // Update the cached copy of the words in the adapter.
            adapter.submitList(products);
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

QRScannerActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            HomeActivity.productViewModel.insert(new ProductModel(rawValue, "100"));
        }
    }).start();

}
```

ProductListAdapter

```
public class ProductListAdapter extends ListAdapter<ProductModel, ProductListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public ProductListAdapter(@NonNull DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ProductModel> diffCallback) {
    super(diffCallback);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return ViewHolder.create(parent);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ProductModel productModel = getItem(position);
    holder.bind(productModel);
}

public static class ProductDiff extends DiffUtil.ItemCallback<ProductModel> {

    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(@NonNull ProductModel oldItem, @NonNull ProductModel newItem) {
        return oldItem == newItem;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(@NonNull ProductModel oldItem, @NonNull ProductModel newItem) {
        return Objects.equals(oldItem, newItem);
    }
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView productImage;
    public TextView textProductTitle;
    public TextView textProductCost;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.productImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_product_image);
        this.textProductTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_product_name);
        this.textProductCost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_product_cost);
    }

    public static ViewHolder create(ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.product_list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    public void bind(ProductModel productModel) {
        textProductTitle.setText(productModel.getProductName());
        textProductCost.setText("$ " + productModel.getProductPrice());
    }
}
}
```

productDao

```
@Dao
public interface productDAO {

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
void insertProduct(ProductModel productModel);

@Query("DELETE FROM productmodel")
void deleteAll();

@Query("SELECT * FROM productmodel ORDER BY productID ASC")
List<ProductModel> getAllProducts();
}
```

RoomDBMaster

```
@Database(entities = ProductModel.class, version = 1)
public abstract class RoomDBMaster extends RoomDatabase {

private static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 4;
public static final ExecutorService databaseWriteExecutor =
        Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);
private static volatile RoomDBMaster INSTANCE;
private static final RoomDatabase.Callback sRoomDatabaseCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onCreate(db);

        databaseWriteExecutor.execute(() -> {
            // Populate the database in the background.
            // If you want to start with more words, just add them.
            productDAO dao = INSTANCE.productDAO();
            dao.deleteAll();

            ProductModel productModel = new ProductModel();
            dao.insertProduct(productModel);
        });
    }
};

public static RoomDBMaster getDatabase(final Context context) {
    if (INSTANCE == null) {
        synchronized (RoomDBMaster.class) {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                                RoomDBMaster.class, "QRProduct_database")
                        .addCallback(sRoomDatabaseCallback)
                        .build();
            }
        }
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

public abstract productDAO productDAO();
}
```

ProductRepository

```
public class ProductRepository {
private final productDAO mProductDao;
private LiveData<List<ProductModel>> mAllProductsList;

public ProductRepository(Application application) {
    RoomDBMaster db = RoomDBMaster.getDatabase(application);
    mProductDao = db.productDAO();
    try {
        mAllProductsList = (LiveData<List<ProductModel>>) mProductDao.getAllProducts();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public LiveData<List<ProductModel>> getAllProducts() {
    return mAllProductsList;
}

// You must call this on a non-UI thread or your app will throw an exception. Room ensures
// that you're not doing any long running operations on the main thread, blocking the UI.
public void insert(ProductModel productModel) {
    RoomDBMaster.databaseWriteExecutor.execute(() -> {
        mProductDao.insertProduct(productModel);
    });
}

}
```

ProductViewModel

```
public class ProductViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
private ProductRepository productRepository;
private LiveData<List<ProductModel>> mAllProductsList;

public ProductViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    productRepository = new ProductRepository(application);
    mAllProductsList = productRepository.getAllProducts();
}

public LiveData<List<ProductModel>> getAllProducts() { return mAllProductsList; }

public void insert(ProductModel productModel) { productRepository.insert(productModel); }

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you call the `initUI()` method on multiple lifecycle events? Isn't it enough to call it in `onCreate` and then your `ViewModel` observes all changes within the database and updates the `Adapter`?

Comment: I'm also curious if you can just cast a List<T> to a LiveData<List<T>>: (LiveData<List<ProductModel>>) mProductDao.getAllProducts(); . Maybe change the return type of `getAllProcuts()` to `LiveData<List<ProductModel>>`. Room can return queries as `LiveData`.

Comment: your class 'ProductListAdapter' doesn't show method submitList. check if this method further calls 'notifyDataSetChanged()' method